# While removing duplicates from one list, getting the sum of values from another list

Tags: python, list

I could not find if that was asked before.

I have two lists

```
string_list = ["o1", "o2", "o1", "o1", "o3", "o2"]

value_list = [5, 6, 7, 8, 14, 47]
```

I want to remove duplicates from string_list while getting the sum of all these `strings` values from the `value_list`.

Here what I want to see is:

```
string_result = ["o1", "o2", "o3"]

value_result = [20, 53, 14]
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: how do you get those results? where does 53 come from? what happens to 47? what have you tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can collect the totals in a dict, but using an `OrderedDict` will allow you to preserve the elements of `string_list` in order of first appearance.

```
from collections import OrderedDict

string_list = ["o1", "o2", "o1", "o1", "o3", "o2"]
value_list = [5, 6, 7, 8, 14, 47]

dict_result = OrderedDict()
for (string, value) in zip(string_list, value_list):
    dict_result[string] = dict_result.get(string, 0) + value

string_result = list(dict_result.keys())
value_result = list(dict_result.values())
```

Comment: Note that starting from Python 3.7, `dict` will also preserve insertion order. Use of `OrderedDict` is hence no longer neccessary if you use mentioned Python versions.

Comment: This assumes that the items in the  `string_list` occur in the sorted order, which may not be the case.

Answer (score 1):

```
string_list = ["o1", "o2", "o1", "o1", "o3", "o2"]
value_list = [5, 6, 7, 8, 14, 47]

dct = {}
for idx, i in enumerate(string_list):
    if dct.get(i):
        dct[i] += value_list[idx]
    else:
        dct[i] = value_list[idx]
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a [`defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict):

```
from collections import defaultdict

string_list = ["o1", "o2", "o1", "o1", "o3", "o2"]
value_list = [5, 6, 7, 8, 14, 47]

d = defaultdict(int)
for s, v in zip(string_list, value_list):
    d[s] += v

value_result = [d[s] for s in sorted(d)]  # [20, 53, 14]
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
string_list = ["o1", "o2", "o1", "o1", "o3", "o2"]
value_list = [5, 6, 7, 8, 14, 47]

no_dups = list(set(string_list))
values = [0] * len(no_dups)

for string, number in zip(string_list, value_list):
    values[no_dups.index(string)] += number 

print(no_dups, values)

output: ['o1', 'o2', 'o3'] [20, 53, 14]
```

Answer (score 0):

Just two lines using numpy and list comprehension. First we create the given data:

```
string_list = ["o1", "o2", "o1", "o1", "o3", "o2"]
value_list = [5, 6, 7, 8, 14, 47]
```

And now the solution, which uses boolean indexing in numpy arrays:

```
import numpy as np # ok, three lines if you count the import :)

string_result = [val for val in set(string_list)]
value_result = [sum(np.array(value_list)[(np.array(string_list) == val)]) for val in string_result]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
string_list = ["o1", "o2", "o1", "o1", "o3", "o2"]

value_list = [5, 6, 7, 8, 14, 47]

result = {k:0 for k in string_list}
for k, v in zip(string_list, value_list):
    result[k] += v

print(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

if the order is not important you can have:

```
from itertools import groupby

string_list = ["o1", "o2", "o1", "o1", "o3", "o2"]
value_list = [5, 6, 7, 8, 14, 47]

string_list, value_list = [list(o) for o in zip(*{k : sum(e[1] for e in v) for k, v in groupby(sorted(zip(string_list, value_list)), key=lambda x: x[0])}.items())]
```